# What can I do when my question doesn't receive enough attention?

Tags: support, questions, bounties, specific-question

I have a question where no one has replied or commented yet. It has an open bounty for 2 days now.

What else can you do, besides the bounty, to gain more attention for your question?

I have improved the [question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816648/css-gradient-not-working-on-ios) a few times, but that didn't have the effect I hoped for.

Comment: Nothing. Bounties are the only real solution.

Comment: Think about tagging with high traffic tags like [css].

Comment: @juergend that's a good one. Stupid from me not to mention [css] lol :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the bounties, you can drum up your own interest on Facebook, your classes, your workplace, etc.

I don't know the etiquette of SO Chat very well, but I suppose if you're active in the chat room before you start asking for help, you might receive some if you ask for it.

Or -- GASP -- post it to Experts Exchange or some other programming forum or Q&A place.

--------------- (Ducks and runs for cover) ----------------